# Command-Click from Objective-C source to Swift opens MyProject-Swift.h File

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift

I have an XCode project that used to be Objective-C but now includes some Swift classes mixed in.  Everything is set up right for building, with my bridging header and MyProject-Swift.h file.  So that's fine.

My problem is that if I'm looking at Objective-C source and I command click a class or method name, instead of opening my Swift file it opens up the MyProject-Swift.h file.  This is driving me crazy and forcing me to use Quick Open manually on the Swift file.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Nobody? Really...

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 9 solved the problem.
you can press cmd + control and click this "name"
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdtYQ.png